# How do I get the top facet fields from a Solr search

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I’m running a Solr query that has thousands of facet fields. I'm not able to reduce the list as yet.

After running the query, I'd like to return the "top 10" facets based on a count. Is this possible using additional query parameters?

Comment: try using facet.offset and facet.limit in the query

Comment: Thanks for the input @AbhijitBashetti. I've ended up using a `facet.sort` (by count) and `facet.limit`. I realised that I didn't have enough context to my original question.